# Changing ASP.NET buttons in CODE BEHIND

Tags: asp.net, button

When I use ..

```
<asp:Button ID="btnSubmitJob" runat="server" CssClass="mybutton"/>
```

and then in my code use ... in the Form Load, the button text is still blank.

```
btnSubmitJob.Attributes.Item("value") = "123"
```

Anyone know why?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: use btnSubmitJob.Text="123", if you want to change button text on Form load as button is server control

Comment: Thank you. I was over complicating it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use this one instead of `btnSubmitJob.Attributes.Item("value") = "123"` in codebehind:

```
btnSubmitJob.Text= "123";
```

Comment: Thank you. I was over complicating it.

Answer (score 0):

Just use the button in your "code behind file", that's the benefit of `runat="server"` which makes it a server side control.

So: `btnSubmitJob.Text = "123";`

Also - if you want to add attributes in the code behind, you'll need to use the Add unless the attribute exists already:

`btnSubmitJob.Attributes.Add("name", "value")`

but for Text there's no reason to do that.